# Creating an NPM START script in package.json

Tags: json, node.js, npm, server, dependencies

So I'm trying to create a script that when someone makes *npm start* it starts a localhost.
Now this is what I have on my **package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run open",
    "open": "concurrently \"http-server -a localhost -p 1234\" \"sleepms 1000 && open http://localhost:1234/public/index.htm\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },

"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "opn-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "sleep-ms": "^2.0.1"
  }
```

But what I'm getting is a 404 of the localhost...

---

Other question, is it possible to make so that when the user types *npm start* it installs or updates all dependencies?

I just recently started with Web development, please have that in mind...

Thank you

Comment: Ok, so I found out that if I add under the **scripts** in package.json _"prestart: "npm install"_ it installs or updates the dependencies upon typing _npm start_

Answer (score 0):

You should have a directory `public` in the root of your project that contains an index.html file.

Comment: And I do have it.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [`http-server` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)...

> `http-server [path] [options]`
>
> [path] defaults to ./public if the folder exists, and ./ otherwise.

Since you are not passing a path, it's defaulting to ./public as its root directory, so you do not need to include `/public` in your URL.

Try accessing http://localhost:1234/index.htm instead of http://localhost:1234/public/index.htm